# C/C++ interop and enums

Tags: c++, c, enums

I wish to expose a C++ library through C functions so that it can be used from C and other languages that can import C code. Some of the C++ methods I will wrap in C function calls take `enum` values coming from types defined like this in the C++ library:

```cpp
enum FooFromCPP { // From C++
    x = 0,
    y,
    z
}
```

The problem I have is that I need a way to make this enum available to the C code, but I don't see a way to do this apart from recreating an equivalent enum in the header I will import from C:

```c
enum FooC { // C equivalent
    x_c = 0,
    y_c,
    z_c
}
```

My first question is, if I have an enum defined in a C++ header of a library I'm using, would there be an easier way to make it available to my C code instead of copying it? I don't think just importing the header that contains it would work since it also contains C++ types that aren't C compatible.

My second question is that I would like to know if the memory layout of the enum in C will be compatible with the corresponding C++ enum? Is it valid to cast the C enum to the C++ one to call the C++ method from my C warper like this?

```cpp
void bar(MyClassPointer* ptr, FooC fooEnum) {
    ((MyClassCPP*)ptr).bar((FooFromCPP)fooEnum);
}
```

Comment: Use the `C` enum in the `C++` code and remove the C++ enum ie include the C header in the C++ code.  If you have a public C interface you should use this in your C++ implementation code rather than duplicating the definitions.  This also removes the chance of accidental inconsistency.

Comment: You can always use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to exclude code only working in C++ when compiling a C translation unit, but why not declare `FooC` in the C header and use the `FooC` enum in the C++ lib, both declarations seem to be exactly the same? You may be even be able to avoid renaming by adding `using FooFromCPP = FooC;` in one of your internal C++ headers...

Comment: @RichardCritten I might consider doing this indeed since I do have the possibility of modifying the C++ library, thanks! In the case I couldn't would there have been any other alternative that would been better to what I proposed?

Comment: @fabian Thanks! Same question as in my previous comment: I think I will be able to do what you advised since I can modify the C++ sources, but apart from what I am doing here would I have had any other alternative if it wasn't possible?

Comment: Also one last question: was the cast correct in terms of memory representation even if redundant? I read the C and C++ enums didn't have the same size in memory.

Comment: "I read the C and C++ enums didn't have the same size in memory" This doesn't happen if you use literally the same declaration for C and C++ enums. (There is no mention of it in the standard, but all implementations guarantee this, otherwise C++ would be DOA).

Comment: I've seen C libraries that add a typedef for an integral type that can hold the enum value and use it everywhere in function signatures, ect.: `enum FooC { ... }; typedef int32_t FooC_t; void bar MyClassPointer* ptr, FooC_t fooEnum) {...}`. Note that you're probably not able to use `MyClassPointer` since C only allows you to use `struct`s. You may need to go with `void*` there. Perhaps you could create a type alias that gives an indication though: `typedef void* MyClassPtr;`

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to use the c++ enum directly in your c code.
As stated in the comments, put the enum in the c part of your code and import it in the c++ code. But this inserts the enum into the global namespace.

If you don't want that, there are other less nice options:

- Write the enum in the c and c++ code. To enforce there are equal, use some static asserts. ([example (enum class instead of plain enum)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72123990/13093284))
- Write a macro so the pre-processor generates two enums for the c++ and c code with the same entries. This adds the possibility of namespaces. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72125616/13093284))